# Trigger more than 50 AWS codepipelines manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-devops

We have more than 50 AWS pipelines. we want to trigger manually. Right now I found one solution in which I have to create a Jenkins job with AWS-CLI code as in shell script, check box parameter(to choose specific pipeline(s)).

```sh
for pipeline_name in $(echo $pipeline_names | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
  #To Start execution of Pipeline
  aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --region 'region' --name $pipeline_name
done
```

Can someone suggest to me how I can do it with the CVS file(with AWS pipeline Information ) as an input to the program and trigger those pipeline(s)?

Or any other suggestions are also welcome:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [panda](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library of python which is easy to use as most of developer use that.